# how to highlight table rows by column variable in gt?

Tags: r, dplyr, colors, gt

I have a dataset wherein I want to have all rows of a certain variable be the same color. There are 4 variables that would ideally each be highlighted a different color. for ex, using the dataset `iris` all rows of Species `setosa` would be green, `versicolor` would be purple, etc.

here are some of the options I tried

```
iris%>%
gt()%>%
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#D9654B")
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
        rows = Species == versicolor))
```

```
iris%>%
  gt () %>%
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = "lightblue"),
            locations = cells_body(columns=("Species"),
                                   rows =("Species"== "versicolor")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use multiple `tab_style`s, one for each category or use e.g. `purrr::reduce` or `Reduce` to add the styles by looping over the categories

Note: I simplified the example data to just two rows per species.

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
pal_color <- c("green", "purple", "yellow")
names(pal_color) <- c("versicolor", "setosa", "virginica")

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  slice_head(n = 2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  gt() %>%
  purrr::reduce(
    names(pal_color),
    ~ tab_style(.x,
      style = list(
        cell_fill(color = pal_color[[.y]])
      ),
      locations = cells_body(
        rows = Species == .y
      )
    ),
    .init = .
  )
```

[image]